# LINQ Select Query results in timeout

Tags: sql-server, linq, performance

I have a Select query that takes about 10 seconds to run if I run it from SQL Server Management Studio (which already implies it's a MSSQL database).  The Select query works on a view which has a couple of joins, which is the reason why it takes about 10 seconds when executing a raw SELECT statement.

The equivalent LINQ statement however ends up with a timeout exception.  Why is this happening and what can do to fix it?

Comment: Can you post both the linq and sql queries?

Comment: @Albin: Only 56 records are returned.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar situation a while back, where a stored proceudre took about 1 second to execute when called from SSMS, but the same procedure (with the same parameters) was timing out when called from the front end application. I ran SQL profiler and saw that i was getting a different execution plan for the stored procedure, when called from the front end, than the one i got when running the sproc from SMSS.(till date i dont know why this happened)

So just try running SQL profiler to see if for some reason the query optimizer chooses a different query plan when executing the query using LINQ. (You need to change the standard options in the profiler to have it display the query plan)

Answer (score 0):

[ARITHABORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306.aspx) is ON by default in SSMS and OFF by default for a SqlClient connection.

See if this solves your issue:

```
new SqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT ON", connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
```